# FFmpeg conversion fails due to network error: “Connection reset by peer…”

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

```
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Connection reset by peer:42.28 bitrate= 523.3kbits/s speed=   1x
[flv @ 0x36f74a0] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x36f74a0] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
Error writing trailer of rtmp://URL Connection reset by peerframe=220186 fps= 29 q=-1.0 Lsize=  489473kB time=02:07:42.32 bitrate= 523.3kbits/s speed=   1x
video:389899kB audio:89794kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.038606%
Conversion failed!
```

I've tried many different commands , but this conversion error is coming at very random timing

```
ffmpeg -re -i TJ36to69.mp4 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -s 426x240 -bufsize 6000k -vb 400k -maxrate 1500k -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -g 30 -r 30 -f flv "rtmp:url"
```

This sometimes can run for 1-2 hours , sometimes 30mins , very random "conversion failed"

Question
Is this an connection issue that dropped that caused this ?
Is there anyway I could ignore the error and move on for "bad" conversion

Comment: Does FFMPEG try to "reconnect" ? Or is that the reason why Conversion Failed occured

Comment: @FlyingAtom I'm only commenting because you requested me to on another question. Unfortunately, I don't have an answer...I don't do much streaming or network stuff. You didn't provide any method for us to attempt to duplicate the issue (not always easy for network related issues). Your console output is missing info about your `ffmpeg` configuration and version, so all I can recommend is to use a recent build from the current git master branch. See [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links. Also, is `ffmpeg` the only tool that fails when outputting to the same address?